# How to allow certain password always in Filenet P8 using Authentication.UserCredentials?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I am implementing a solution in Filenet P8 where I want to allow the users who are logging in as some "Password" when they log on using Filenet.Api.Authentication.UserCredentials.

Anyone implemented similar solution?

Comment: Please clarify your requirement. i have also worked on similar scenario where i make a connection with CE

Answer (score 1):

FileNet has no implementation for authentication process, only for authorization. FN authenticate users through JAAS implementation of Application Server.

You can implement and register in Application Server your own login module (JAAS spec) to authenticate user in not standard way.

This is only one way to change authentication mechanism for FileNet.